# MvcSiteMapProvider to lazy load dynamic nodes

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I'd like to use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for building breadcrumbs for an MVC3 project.

My problem is that certain dynamic nodes could have hundreds of dynamic child nodes, each of which could have hundreds of subnodes itself - so reading the whole sitemap is not an option. Instead, I'd like to lazy-load subnodes for a given node when a user lands on the page.

As far as I can see, this is not possible with MvcSiteMapProvider, but maybe I'm missing something? Is there a recommended way to address that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - I haven't got any answers and, unfortunately, it seems the correct answer is that lazy loading is not supported by MVCSiteMapProvider.

So I created a quick prototype of a very leightweight [MVC breadcrumbs generator](https://github.com/andreister/MvcBreadcrumbs), which would request nodes only when you actually visit the corresponding page.